# PowerDesigner : format MCD display

Tags: powerdesigner

Doing reverse engineering with powerDesigner, I have complicated CDM. Is there a way to ask powerDesigner to display it properly (nicely) ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `Symbol > Auto-Layout` menu, which will provide various options of auto-layout.

Then you could create more diagrams to move clusters of entities to these diagrams...